# Как написать Cron на Python?

Tags: python

Используя готовые либы сначала засетапить лог, потом как я рассказывал прочитать кронтаб и сформировать лист тасков, потом зайти в вечный цикл и крутится там проверяя время. Пока время таски не совпадет, в этот момент форкаться для выполнения таски.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: с asyncio или обычный?

Comment: @eri крон подразумевает запуск задач в отдельных процессах, так что использовать asyncio наверное просто нет смысла?